# Proving $|A-B| = |A| - |A\cap B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $U$ be the universal set.
I can see this with the aid of a venn diagram.

However, what is wrong with this?
$$|A-B|:= |A\cap B^{\complement}|\\ = |A- (A\cap B)|\\ := |A\cap (A\cap B)^{\complement}| \\ = |A| + |(A\cap B)^{\complement}| - |A\cup(A^{\complement} \cup B)| \\ = |A| + |(A\cap B)^{\complement}| - |U| $$
which can't be true since in general,
$$|U| \neq |A| + |(A\cap B)^{\complement}|- |A-B|...$$

Comment: But $|A \cap (A \cap B)^c| = |A \cap (A^c \cup B^c)|= |(A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B^c)| = |A \cap B^c|$.

Comment: Yep, but then that means I showed $|U| = |A|$ right?

Comment: Where this ????

Comment: From my first line, and then with my last equality

Comment: You start with a "universe" $U$ and you define inside it two sets $A$ and $B$ partly overlapping. It is not necessary to assume that $A$ is the whole universe $U$.

Comment: You have the universe $U$ of Human Being with inside the set $A$ of Males and the set $B$ of French. $A$ and $B$ will partly overlap but $A$ is not the set of all Humans.

Comment: If you go on with your calculations and apply again the [principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Union_and_intersection), what you get is: $|A|+|(A \cap B)^c|−|U|= |A| + |A^c \cup B^c| -|U| = |A|+|A^c|+|B^c|-|A^c \cap B^c|-|U|$. But $|A|+|A^c|=|U|$ and thus we can sumplify to: $|B^c|-|A^c \cap B^c|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything that's really wrong with that, only that it didn't end up with what you tried to prove.

As for your comment in the end I'd like to see a case where

$$|U| \ne |A| + |(A\cap B)^C| - |A-B|$$

The general approach is to decompose the sets into a disjoint partition of the universe (that is in terms of the sets $A\cap B$, $A\cap B^C$, $A^C\cap B$ and $A^C\cap B^C$). You then have

$$|A| = |(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^C)| = |A\cap B| + |A\cap B^C|$$
$$|(A\cap B)^C| = |(A\cap B^C)\cup(A^C\cap B)\cup(A^C\cap B^C)| = |(A\cap B^C)|+|(A^C\cap B)|+|(A^C\cap B^C)|$$
$$|A-B| = |A\cap B^C|$$

Comment: Yep, there is no case. I had drawn out my diagrams incorrectly. I realise if I continued on from $|(A\cap B)^c| = |U| - |A\cap B|$ I get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to cardinals, addition is easier to work with since it corresponds to the union of two disjoint sets.

But as luck would have it, $A-B$ and $A\cap B$ are disjoint. So, $$|A-B|+|A\cap B|=|(A-B)\cup(A\cap B)|.$$

From this point, the solution should be fairly obvious.